# Replication error from Mariadb 10.1 to Mysql 5.1/5.0/5/5 when master's logging format is set to row based

Tags: mysql, replication, binlog, row, mariadb-10.1

While replicating from Mariadb 10.1 to MySQL (5.0, 5.1, 5.5) or Mariadb (5.2, 5.5) lower versions, if master's `binlog_format` is set to row,  the replication failure occurs with the following message at slave (`show slave status \G;`):

> Last_Error: Table definition on master and slave does not match: Column 18 type mismatch - received type 19, rtmariadb10.empdetails
>   has type 11

Here

```
Master: Mariadb 10.1,binlog_format: row ; 
Slave : Mysql 5.1, binlog_format=statement/row/mixed(any one of these)
```

Can someone please help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered one of the reasons for saying that replication must not go from a newer Master to an older Slave.

Would you care to explain the ultimate goal; maybe we can discuss a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,My ultimate goal is to solve this error for row based replication , i have searched a lot for a suitable solution to this , but have not been successful to understood what is the cause of this error, it will be a great help if i get this

Comment: Please step back further -- Why are you attempting to replicate from a new Master to an old Slave.

Comment: (When I cannot answer a question as asked, I try to provide a workaround.  In your situation, I don't have enough knowledge of the bigger picture to know what to "work around".)

Comment: yes , i got your point. Actually i am working in a team which is upgrading old databases ,both mysql and mariadb to Mariadb 10.1 . So as a part of the process i have to perform a poc to ckeck backward and forward replication between the old and new database versions. That's where i got stucked. Everything is working fine in replication set up except the case where i set master to row based logging , mainly the above mentioned issue is coming in this case

Comment: You have found an replication situation that will not work.  Plan A:  Don't replicate from new to old.  Plan B:  Use SBR, not RBR.  Plan C:  Something else.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `BLACKHOLE` engine in a "relay" server.  I don't now the specifics for your situation, but look at:

Master -- new version -->
Relay -- intermediate version -->
Slave -- old version

The Relay would receive the data and pass it on to the Slave without even storing it ("Blackhole").  The hope is that with a suitable intermediate version and/or using SBR on one side and RBR on the other, you can avoid your problem.

Comment: I never tried, but I think this cannot work in a normal situation. Since BLACKHOLE won't store any row, UPDATEs and DELETEs are never written to the binlog, and never replicated.