# Is it possible to create a MySQL slave from a MariaDB master?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, high-availability, master-slave-replication

I need to create a MySQL slave instance which replicates the data from a MariaDB master. (I guess it won't work.) Any advice on how to create this replica architecture using MariaDB and MySQL?

I am also investigating and considering using [tungsten](https://www.continuent.com/solutions/tungsten-replicator-all-you-need-to-know/). Does anybody have experience with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think it can work, see e.g. [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157565/replication-error-from-mariadb-10-1-to-mysql-5-1-5-0-5-5-when-masters-logging-f) (with answers). Note that:

- You won't be able to use GTID replication as this is implemented differently in MariaDB and MySQL
- You need to use versions of MySQL and MariaDB which are somewhat compatible.
- Avoid using any MariaDB-specific features.